# Woocommerce contractor style invoicing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a woocommerce e-commerce website for a client, he currently sells 20 products to do-it-your-selfers and he also does custom installs that include parts, labor and tax himself. Do you know of an extension that allows sending custom (private) products/invoices for the custom installs? He is not tech savy, so he needs to remain in the woo system.